No overload matches this call. when adding controller to your routes files
Im newbie in typescript I been stuck with couple of hours solving this problem.
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<...>' is missing the following properties from type 'Application<Record<string, any>>': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 63 more.ts(2769)

this is my route files I got error from adding registerUser in the argument
import express from "express";
import { registerUser } from "../controller/user-controller";

//routes
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", registerUser);

export default router;

my middleware
//user registration Controller
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express"; // Import the types
import User from "../models/user";

export const registerUser = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email,
    });

    if (user) {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "User Already Exist!" });
    }

    user = new User(req.body);
    await user.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: "User Registered Successfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    res.status(500).send({ message: "Something went Wrong!" });
  }
};


I think you need to replace return res.status(200)... with res.status(200)...; return; because you are not expected to actually return anything from a route handler
